# Why is the output so ?

Tags: postgresql

I have the below code:(Assume initial txid=a)

```
select count(*) from tabl;
--------------------------
count=2;

select current_txid();
--------------------------
a+1;

begin;
insert into tabl values(v1,v2);
insert into tabl values(v3,v4);
commit;

select count(*) from tabl;
--------------------------
count=4;

select current_txid();
--------------------------
a+3
```

Why/how is the current txid=3 should it be more than that as there are multiple sql satements i.e transactions ?

Comment: What do you think `begin; ... commit;` is? And, no, an arbitrary sql statement != transaction.

Comment: Well isn't each 'individual statement ' is a transaction in psql as there's an implict begin and commit at the end of each statement ..  also if you say .. why is the txid incrementd after the initial and ending select statement after all select statements aren't transactions right? (i.e where you have current_txid) so why do I see the txid  as a+3 ?

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name please re-read the question this is not a duplicate ... the psql code is trying to question a concept...

Comment: What are they ? since a begin & commit implies a single transaction..